# multiplyOddByTwo function using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the odd numbers in the following array and then multiply by 2 using `reduce` method but it's giving me `undefined` error. Any help please.

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr % 2 === 0) {
      arr.push(curr);
    } else {
      arr.push(curr * 2)
    }
  }, [])
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: you never return anything in reduce so reduce returns undefined when done.

Comment: You are pushing to the `arr`? Seems wrong

Comment: Can you update with some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: @epascarello 
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    if(curr % 2 === 0){
      acc.push(curr);
    }else{
      acc.push(curr * 2)
    }
  },[])
} 

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1,2,3]));


it returns "cannot read property push of undefined"

Comment: so where is the return? See my first comment.

Comment: In the end you should be using map, not reduce

Comment: You don't use `acc` you probably mixed it up with `arr`. instead of `arr.push(curr)` or `arr.push(curr*2)` use `acc.push(curr)` and `acc.push(curr*2)`. Furthermore you need to return a value from the redcue function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to point out:

1. You have to make modifications to the second param in your reduce function. It is your initial value. The first param in the reduce callback(acc) is your cumulated value up till that particular iteration.
2. You have to return your cumulated value in each iteration. (When in the final iteration, this will be your calculated answer. Here you aren't returning anything hence the undefined)

```
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr % 2 === 0) {
      acc.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push(curr * 2)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3])); // [2,2,6]
```

This multiplies odd index elements by 2.

Edit: That is not undefined error. That is just `undefined` being returned. Any function not returning anything returns `undefined`.

Comment: No issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce - doc link for reduce.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like it to only return odd numbers multiplied by 2 and not return the even then use this:

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
    const odd = arr.filter(num => num % 2 !== 0);
    return odd.map(i => i * 2);
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```

Otherwise if you would like it to return all numbers but multiply odd numbers by 2 then use this:

```js
const multiplyOddByTwo = (arr) => {
    return arr.map(num => num % 2 === 0 ? num : num * 2);
}

console.log(multiplyOddByTwo([1, 2, 3]));
```